# HP Smart Array E200 - Battery Pack for Backup cache card 128MB is discharged

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, boot, hp-smart-array

I cannot boot Windows on my server nor can I boot any OS installation DVD. I was thinking that it may be due to below errors.

I have a HP Smart Array E200. the battery Pack for Backup cache card 128MB is discharged completely. It is installed on my Domain controller. I urgently need to figure out a way to boot up my domain so that I can  construct a mirror Domain controller that will take over the service.

I read that if I enable the Physical Drive Write Cache setting, I may encounter data loss in case of a power failure.

I want to know what data could be lost in case of a power failure. Is it all my data saved on my hard drives or unsaved data only?

If I manually shut down the server and then disconnect the power cables, will it cause data loss as mentioned?

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to boot an OS?

Answer (score 0):

The battery backup is used to provide you with protection from a sudden power loss - the idea is that the battery keeps the cache RAM content of the controller alive and writes it out as soon as power is restored. Naturally, this is only relevant for new data that is not yet written to the disk while the controller cache is used for writes - in that case the OS thinks the data is written, as the controller reported "write complete". This is not necessary when doing an ordinary shutdown of the OS.

Anyway, this should be unrelated to the fact that you can't even boot into an installation DVD.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sven. Concerning the fact that i cannot boot up neither to windows nor to Installation DVD, can you please tell me what could be the reason and how can i make the server boot to windows at least?